# Let $A$ be nonnegative and $A$ is irreducible. why is any nonnegative eigenvector of $A$ is a positive scalar multiple of the Perron vector of $A$?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

Let $A\in M_n$ be nonnegative  and  $A$ is irreducible.  why is any nonnegative
eigenvector of $A$ is a positive scalar multiple of the Perron vector of $A$?

Comment: Have you seen the proof of this fact for *positive* matrices $A$?

Comment: @Omnomnomnom - No dear user,

Answer (score 2):

**Sketch of proof:**

Let $x,y$ denote two non-negative eigenvectors of $A$, with entries $x_i$ and $y_i$ (respectively). Let $\lambda \leq \mu$ be the eigenvalues corresponding to $x$ and $y$ (resp.).

Suppose that $x_i \neq 0 \implies y_i = 0$ for $1 \leq i \leq n$.  Deduce that $A$ is reducible.

Suppose, on the other hand, that there is an $i$ for which both $x_i$ and $y_i$ are non-zero. Suppose that $\lambda \neq \mu$.  Now, it suffices to find a positive number $\alpha$ such that $x - \alpha y \geq 0$, but $A(x - \alpha y) < 0$. This is  contradiction of the positivity of $A$.

Finally, it suffices to prove that the Perron eigenvector has geometric  multiplicity $1$.

Comment: In which part used of the Perron vector? Please more guide.

Comment: @H.S I don't understand your question. Any irreducible non-negative matrix has a Perron vector

Comment: Nevermaind, but, i  don't understand this part " If $x_i \neq 0 \implies y_i = 0$ for $1 \leq i \leq n$."

Comment: @H.S see your earlier question. If this occurs, then $A$ has a non-negative eigenvector with some zero entries.